# Can't find module webpack-subresource-integrity after ng serve

Tags: angular, npm

I'm a beginner with Angular and I tried to install bootstrap. Bootstrap didn't work for some reason; therefore I uninstalled it. After running the command `ng serve` I got this error that says `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack-subresource-integrity'`

What this issue could be?

Here's a picture of the full message:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue with:

```
delete package-lock.json
delete node_modules
delete dist (if exist)

npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

Comment: Is there a command for deleting `node_modules` folder? Because deleting that folder manually doesn't delete everything.

Comment: you need to delete manually, right-click and delete.
Then run the two npm command

Comment: Not everything is deleted, is that ok?

Comment: can you add a image of the src folder after the delete?

Comment: I just done all the steps and it says `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ashaat01\OneDrive - EchoStar Corporation\Desktop\Angular Projects\rack-elevation\node_modules\bootstrap'`

Comment: did you run npm install on the client folder?

Comment: It was in the project folder. idk if this is considered the client folder. Sorry, I'm completely new to Angular

Comment: Anyway, why it's looking for bootstrap even after uninstalling it?